# Why is createRecord() in child component giving an error only when placed within a parent component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lwc with a record-edit-form in the html file and createRecord() in the js. When I put the component on a record page by itself, everything works fine. But when I place it as a child within a parent component, it gives an error saying the object is undefined. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Child HTML:

```
...
         <template>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Responsibilities__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Area_of_Responsibility__c" value={recordId} disabled></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Description_Long__c"></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Link_to_Documentation__c"></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                                  type="reset"
                                  label="Cancel"
                                  onclick={handleCancel}>
                </lightning-button>
                <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                                  type="submit"
                                  label="Submit"
                                  onclick={handleSubmit}>
                </lightning-button>
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
            </div>
        </template>
...
```

Child JS:

```
...
    handleSubmit(event) {     
        event.preventDefault();
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        createRecord({Responsibilities__c, fields})
            .then(() => {return refreshApex(this.wiredResponsibilitiesResult);   
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        this.showForm = false;
    }
...
```

When viewing the parent component, you can interact with the form in the child component. Everything works fine until I hit Submit, then I get a popup that says:

```
A Component Error has occurred!
Message: Responsibilities__c is not defined
Component Descriptor: c:jobDescriptionContainer
```

Parent HTML:

```
...
            <template for:each={aorsForDept} for:item="item">
                <div key={item.Id}>
                <div class="slds-text-heading_small"> {item.Name} </div> 
                    <c-responsibilities-collapsible
                        record-id={item.Id}>
                    </c-responsibilities-collapsible>
                </div> 
            </template>
...
```

Parent JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
...
export default class JobDescriptionContainer extends LightningElement {
    @track aorsForDept = [];
}...    
//I think that's all that's relevant
```

Comment: In this line in the child JS - `createRecord({Responsibilities__c, fields})` - should you have quotes around "Responsibilities__c"?

Comment: I don't think so... the code gave me a syntax error when I tried right now to change that.

Answer (score 1):

The call to createRecord has the wrong parameters. Update your code to first import your schema object:

```
import RESPONSIBILITIES from '@salesforce/schema/Responsibilities__c';
```

Then make the call:

```
createRecord({apiName: RESPONSIBILITIES.objectApiName, fields})
```

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. Idk why this didn't do the trick exactly, but it did help me figure it out. I got it to work when I used ({apiName: "Responsibilities__c", fields})

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it when I changed the call to:

```
createRecord({apiName: "Responsibilities__c", fields})
```

I also changed the HTML for the form and moved the action {handleSubmit} from the Submit button to the record-edit-form properties. It now reads:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Responsibilities__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess}
                            onsubmit={handleSubmit}>  <!--MOVED IT HERE-->
                ...
   <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                     type="submit"
                     label="Submit">                                
                    <!--PREVIOUSLY HAD IT HERE-->
   </lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Thanks to Phil and Brian, who both pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Ah, I didn't spot you not using onsubmit...